# Heroku view files changed by client

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-api

I made a simple Node.js server and deployed it to Heroku that serves a dead simple HTML form that returns submitted value to

```
fs.writeFile('./users.json',JSON.stringify(dataArr,null,4),(err)=>{
    if(err){console.log(err);}
    console.log('file saved');
  });
```

In Heroku's logs I can see "new file written" but I can't find a way to retrieve the saved information from the `users.json` file. When I try to do a pull request from Heroku, it says that everything is already up to date, even though in Heroku logs I can see "new file written".

How can I see the change in my `users.json` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to open it from your JavaScript code like any other file, but there's a huge catch: *[Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)*. Any changes you make to it will be lost when your dyno restarts, [which happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting).

If you need to store data for any meaningful amount of time you'll have to put it elsewhere. Heroku [recommends using something like Amazon S3 for file storage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3), or you could use a [client-server database like PostgreSQL](https://www.heroku.com/postgres).

Based on its filename I'd guess a database is a better option here, though of course without knowing what `users.json` actually contains and how it's used I can't say for sure.

Comment: The problem is i dont know how to access new instance of users.json(file that stores newly created username/pass) on heroku. when i try to 'git pull heroku master' it doesn't update new users that have added new username/password via fs.writeFile,but instead it trows me a message sayng, 'everything is up to date' even tho users.json file has changed on heroku.(of course before dyno reset).

Comment: @GlitchFish, committing changes to files on Heroku and pulling them to your local machine isn't a good strategy here (but of course you'd need to `add` and `commit` the files before you can `pull` new commits). For starters, data shouldn't be tracked in your repository. Ignoring that, you can't really predict when dyno restarts will happen so there's a significant opportunity to lose data. I _strongly_ urge you to save your data some other way, e.g. into a PostgreSQL database (probably better) or a remote object store like Amazon S3 as I have suggested.

Comment: @GlitchFish, as an aside, I hope you are also pushing your work to a real Git host: "[Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as GitHub and treat that as canonical.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app)"